# Node server Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm a complete node newbie, and I'm running into a problem:

```
var http    = require("http");
var url     = require('url');
var fs      = require('fs');
var io      = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){ 
console.log('Connection');
var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

switch(path){
    case '/':
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
        response.write('Hello World');
        break;
    case '/socket.html':
        fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
            if (error){
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write("This doesn't exist - 404");
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('hi!'); // **************<---- I'm getting here
                response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                response.write(data, 'utf8');
            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write("This page does not exist - 404");
        console.log(path);
        break;
}
response.end(); 
}); 

server.listen(8001);

io.listen(server);
```

I'm getting to the console.log() inside the 'else', but response.write does not output anything at all, If I console.log(data) I get

Comment: I'm getting to the console.log() inside the 'else', but response.write does not output anything at all, If I console.log(data) I get <buffer 84 02 etc etc, I have tried the toString method on data, that worked to log out the html I expected, but I still can't write the data like I need to, Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: [`fs.readFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) is an asynchronous call, so it won't execute those `respone.write` funtions _immediately_, thus `response.end();` got executed, and since `response` is closed, nothing is written.

Comment: @Passerby please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should have .end called after write.

```
response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
response.write(data, 'utf8');
response.end();
```

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding

Answer (score 1):

Extending from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243650/node-server-issue?noredirect=1#comment28493222_19243650):

[`fs.readFile()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) is an asynchrnous call, which means it will simply tell Node to try to open the file, and then move on **without waiting for it**. So by this code:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
    if (error){
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write("This doesn't exist - 404");
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('hi!'); // **************<---- I'm getting here
        response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(data, 'utf8');
    }
});
response.end();
```

What this code does is:

1. You: "Hey Node, open this file for me; when you're done, tell me";
2. You: "End the response, I don't need that anymore.";
3. (*Unknown* time later)
   Node: "Hi, the file is ready.".
   You: "Cool, now write the file to response stream."
   Node: "...WTF man, you've closed the stream!"

(OK I added the last line)

So to do what you intended, you have two options:

1. Make the file open operation synchronously using [`fs.readFileSync()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options), so you can do the "linear" programming you're familiar with:

   ```
   try {
       var data=fs.readFileSync(__dirname+path,{"encoding":"utf8"});
       response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
       response.write(data,"utf8");
   }catch(e){
       response.writeHead(400,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
       response.write("This doesn't exist -  404");
   }
   response.end();
   ```
2. End the response in the callback function of `fs.readFile()`, not in server listener:

   ```
   switch(path){
       case '/':
           response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
           response.write('Hello World');
           response.end();/* here */
           break;
       case '/socket.html':
           fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
               if (error){
                   response.writeHead(404);
                   response.write("This doesn't exist - 404");
                   response.end(); /* here */
                   console.log(error);
               } else {
                   console.log('hi!');
                   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                   response.write(data, 'utf8');
                   response.end(); /* here */
               }
           });
           break;
       default:
           response.writeHead(404);
           response.write("This page does not exist - 404");
           response.end(); /* here */
           console.log(path);
           break;
   }
   //response.end(); <-- get rid of this line
   ```

Also please be noticed that I change [`404` to `200`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) in the `writeHead()` call when file open is succeeded, I guess that's what you actually mean.